# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, telerik-grid

Story:

I have a strange error when I try to save something I got this error message

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

I really don’t know what that is and why is it appear, it appears only when I try to save something my insert and update is working, only when I try to save something in db from my Telerik grid

```
    if (this.annualVacationList != null)
        {
            List<AnnualVacation> vacationToSave = this.annualVacationList;
            IEnumerable<AnnualVacation> existing = paramUser.AnnualVacations;
            foreach (AnnualVacation toSave in vacationToSave)
            {
                AnnualVacation existingItem = existing.Where(x => x.AnnualVacationId == toSave.AnnualVacationId).SingleOrDefault();
                if (existingItem == null)
                {
                    ctx.AddToAnnualVacations(toSave);
                }
                else
                {
                    existingItem.FromDate = toSave.FromDate;
                    existingItem.ToDate = toSave.ToDate;
                    existingItem.WorkingTime = toSave.WorkingTime;
                    existingItem.VacationDays = toSave.VacationDays;
                }
            }
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

After debugging I have seen that the code brake down in the Project.Name.Designer.cs
..... O.o

```
  public void AddToAnnualVacations(AnnualVacation annualVacation)
    {
        base.AddObject("AnnualVacations", annualVacation);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heey

I got it by myself somehow viewstates are not Detaching the context and that was the problem I have just created

```
var tmp = new AnnualVacation
                    {
                        FromDate = toSave.FromDate,
                        ToDate = toSave.ToDate,
                        WorkingTime = toSave.WorkingTime,
                        VacationDays = toSave.VacationDays,
                        UserId = toSave.UserId
                    };
```

in the same if query that is above (if(existing Item==null)) and it works
but still thanks for everyone that tried to help me ^^